# General divisibility tests of form $\, 7\mid10b+a\!\iff\! 7\mid b-2a\!\iff\! 7\mid b+5a$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am currently helping a friend with their problem sheet. They have been given the question

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ have digits $a_r, \dots a_1,a_0$, so that

$$n=10^ra_r+\dots+10^2a_2+10a_1+a_0 = 10b+a_0$$

Prove that $\,7\mid n\,$ if and only if $\,7\mid 10^{r-1}a_r+\dots+a_1-2a_0 = b-2a_0$.

I have attempted this. First, I remarked that 10 is congruent to 3 mod 7, which gives us $(10)^s\equiv (3)^s\mod 7$, and hence $n\equiv a_0+3a_1+\dots+(3)^ra_r\mod 7$. So $7|n\iff n\equiv0\mod 7$.

However I'm unsure as to where to go from here. If I continue in the same manner I reach a result that is nothing like that which I am required to prove.

Could I have some elucidation as to which way I should go from here?

Comment: It is not clear if $10^{r-1}a_r+\dots+a_1-2a_0$ means $10^{r-1}a_r+ a_{r-1} + ...a_3 + a_2 +a_1-2a_0$ or whether it means $10^{r-1}a_r+ 10^{r-2}a_{r-1}\dots+ 10a_2+a_1-2a_0$

Comment: Call it $\,\bar n.\, $ Then $\ n = 10\bar n + 21a_0\ $ so $\ 7\mid n\iff 7\mid 10\bar n\iff 7\mid \bar n\  \ $

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2306045/589

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961065/11619).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules of thumb for divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961065/rules-of-thumb-for-divisibility)

Answer (score 12):

[Below we use congruence (modular) arithmetic, notably the [congruence sum and product rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Readers unfamiliar with congruences please skip ahead to "Without mod" below, and note that the notation $\ a\mid b\ $ means $\ a\,$ divides $\,b,\,$ i.e. $\, an = b\,$ for some integer $\,n$].

Let's *derive* the test. Let $\, n = 10b + a\,$ for $\,a = $ units digit. Working $\!\bmod 7,\,$ the idea is to simplify $\,b$'s coefficient $\,10\,$ to $\,1,\,$ by scaling $\,n\,$ by $\,\color{#c00}{10^{-1}\equiv -2},\ $ by $\, \color{#c00}{-2\cdot 10\equiv 1}\pmod{\!7},\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{align} 7\ \mid\  10b+a\ \,&\\
\iff\qquad\! 10 b+a\ \,& \equiv 0\pmod{\!7}\\
\color{red}\iff  \color{#c00}{-2}\,(\color{#c00}{10}b+a)&\equiv 0\ \ \ \ {\rm by\ \ } {-2} \times \rm prior\\
\iff\qquad\ \   b\color{#0a0}{-2}a\ &\equiv 0\ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \  \color{#c00}{{-}20\equiv 1}\\
\iff\qquad\ \   b\color{#0a0}{+5}a\ &\equiv 0\ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \  \color{#0a0}{{-}2\ \equiv\ 5}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

$${\rm so}\ \quad \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{7\mid 10b+a\iff 7\mid b-2a\iff 7\mid b+5a}\qquad\qquad\qquad $$

The same works for any divisor $\,d\,$ coprime to $10$ using $\,\color{#c00}{c\equiv 10^{-1}\pmod{\!d}}$

$$\begin{align} d\ \mid\  10b+a\ \,&\\
\iff\qquad\! 10 b+a\ \,& \equiv 0\pmod{\!d}\\
\color{red}\iff \ \ \  \color{#c00}c\,(\color{#c00}{10}b+a)&\equiv 0\ \ \ \ {\rm by\ \ } c \times \rm prior\\
\iff\qquad\ \   b+\color{#c00}{c}a\ &\equiv 0\ \ \ \ {\rm by}\ \  \color{#c00}{10c\equiv 1}\\
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\ \ \ $$

$${\rm so}\ \quad \bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{d\mid 10b+a\iff d\mid b+\color{#c00}c\:\!a,\,\ \color{#c00}{c\equiv 10^{-1}}\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!d}}\qquad\qquad\quad $$

The $\color{#c00}{\rm second}\!\!\color{red}{\iff}$ is *bidirectional* since scaling by an invertible element is an invertible operation: $ $ to invert scaling by $\color{#c00}{-2}\,$ we scale by its inverse $\color{#c00}{10}$, i.e. $10\,\times$ the second congruence yields the first. Generally - like  equations -  scaling a congruence by an *invertible* number [yields an *equivalent* congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3461547/242) (recall a modular integer is invertible $\!\iff\!$ it is coprime to the modulus, [by Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242)).

This method works for any coprime divisor $\,d\,$ and radix $\,r\,$ exactly as above, i.e.
$$\bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{d\mid r\:\!b\!+\!a\iff d\mid b\!+\color{#c00}{\hat r}a,\ \ {\rm for}\ \ \color{#c00}{\hat r \equiv r^{-1}}\!\!\!\!\!\pmod{\!d}}\qquad $$

**Without mod** $\ $ Eliminating congruence language above yields more elementary proofs

By $\color{#90f}{\rm Lemma}$: $\ \gcd(\color{#c00}{7,-2})=1\, $ so $\, 7\mid 10\,b\,+\,a\ \iff\ \ \color{#c00}{7\,\mid\! {-}2}(10b\!+\!a)\!\color{#0a0}{+\!7(3b)} = b - 2a$

By $\color{#90f}{\rm Lemma}$: $\ \gcd(\color{#c00}{7,\,5})\:=\:1\,$ so $\ 7\mid 10\,b\,+\,a\ \iff\,\  \color{#c00}{7\, \mid\,\ 5}\:(10b\!+\!a)\!\color{#0a0}{-\!7(7b)} =\, b +5a$

$\color{#90f}{\bf Lemma}\ $ If $\, \gcd(\color{#c00}{7,c})=1\,$ then $\ 7\mid n\!\!\!\!\overset{\rm EL\!\!}\iff\!\! \color{#c00}{7\mid c}n\!\!\iff\! \!\color{#c00}{7\mid\, c}\,n  \color{#0a0}{+7\, m}\, $ by $\rm EL = $ [Euclid's Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/252748/242)

**Remark** $ $ The divisibility test works for *all* integers $\,a,b\,$ (not only digits in decimal radix rep), e.g. $\,a,b\,$ can be negative. Said in fractions: $\,10b+a\equiv0\iff b\equiv -a/10\equiv 2a\pmod{\!7}.\,$ Note that the special case $\,a\equiv -1\,$ yields the inverse of $10,\,$ namely $\,1/10\equiv -2.\,$ Exactly the same method as above works for any divisor  $\,d\,$ coprime to the radix $\,r\,$ $(\!\!\iff\! r\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod d)$.

Alternatively we can use the [universal divisibility test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063944/242) which - unlike the above divisibility test which computes only a binary truth value - has the advantage of computing the *remainder*, so can be used to check arithmetic, etc, as in [casting out nines and elevens](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242).

---

Below is a common variant of such divisibility tests, e.g. see [here (deleted)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3939092/242), or [here (brilliant.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506123815/https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/ibraheems-division-theory/?ref_id=1606217)

**Theorem** $ $ If $\,10c\!-\!ud=\color{#c00}1\,$ then $\,10t\!+\!u\mid 10b\!+\!a \iff 10t\!+\!u\mid b\!+\!(c\!+\!dt)a,\,$ e.g.

$$\!\begin{align}&n=10t\!+\!1 \mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(1\!+\!9t)a
\iff n\mid b-t\:\!a\\[.1em]
&n=10t\!+\!3\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(1\!+\!3t)a\\[.1em]
&n=10t\!+\!7\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(5\!+\!7t)a
\iff n\mid b\!-\!(2\!+\!3t)a\\[.1em]
&n=10t\!+\!9\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(1+\:\!t)a\end{align}\qquad\ $$

**Proof** $\bmod \!10t\!+\!u\!:\ 10\,(b\!+\!(c\!+\!dt)a) = 10b\!+\!(\color{#c00}1)a\,$ by $\,10t\equiv -u,\,$ [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242)

$$n=10t\!+\!u\mid 10b+a\iff \color{#0a0}{n\mid 10}\,(b\!+\!(c\!+\!dt)a)\iff n\mid b\!+\!(c\!+\!dt)a\qquad$$

follows by Euclid's Lemma, since $\color{#0a0}{(n,10)} = (10t\!+\!u,10)=(u,10)=\color{#c00}1.\ \small\bf QED$

$10c\!-\!ud=1\Rightarrow\bmod 10\!:\ d\equiv -u^{-1},\,$ e.g. we can choose $\,d = -u^{-1}\bmod 10.$

E.g. $\,u = 1\Rightarrow\, d\equiv -1/1\equiv 9 ,\,$ so $\,c = (1\!+\!ud)/10 = 1,\,$ so

$\qquad\qquad\begin{align}n=10t\!+\!1\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff& n\mid b\!+\!(1\!+\!9t)a\\
\iff& n\mid b-t\:\!a\end{align}$

E.g. $\,u = 3\Rightarrow\, d\equiv -1/3\equiv 9/3\equiv 3,\,$ so $\,c = (1\!+\!ud)/10 = 1,\,$ so

$\qquad\qquad n=10t\!+\!3\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(1\!+\!3t)a$

E.g. $\,u = 7\Rightarrow\, d\equiv -1/7\equiv 9/(-3)\equiv -3\equiv 7,\,$ so $\,c = (1\!+\!ud)/10 = 5,\,$ so

$\qquad\qquad\begin{align}n=10t\!+\!7\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff& n\mid b\!+\!(5\!+\!7t)a\\
\iff& n\mid b\!-\!(2\!+\!3t)a\end{align}$

E.g. $\,u = 9\Rightarrow\, d\equiv -1/9\equiv 9/9\equiv 1 ,\,$ so $\,c = (1\!+\!ud)/10 = 1,\,$ so

$\qquad\qquad n=10t\!+\!9\mid 10b\!+\!a\iff n\mid b\!+\!(1\!+\!t)a$

Comment: Can you write this up in plain English alongside the very dense mathematical notation so it is comprehensible to someone whose high-school math days are far behind them?

Comment: @Lawton It is essential to master modular arithmetic (congruences) if you wish results like this to be more intuitive. You can find good expositions in most any textbook on elementary number theory. If you tell me precisely which inferences are not clear then I can elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: From $n$, subtract $21\cdot a_0$, and then divide the result by $10$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=10a+b$

$$N=7a+(3a+b)$$
$$N=14a+(6a+2b)$$
$$N=21a+(-a +2b)$$
$$-N=-21a+(a-2b)$$
$$21a-N=(a-2b)$$
$$21a-(a-2b)=N$$

If $7|A$ and $7|B$, then $7|(A-B)$ and $7|(A+B)$ by the distributive property.

So $21a$ is clearly divisible by 7. Then if $7|(a-2b)$, $7|N$.

Conversely, $21a-N=(a-2b)$. If $7|N$, then $7|(a-2b)$.

So $7|N$ iff $7|(a-2b)$

By similar reasoning, $7|N$ iff $7|(3a+b)$.

You  might want to try a similar proof for :

Given, $N=100a+10b+c$, $7|n$ iff   $7|(2a+3b+c)$

Answer (score 0):

Because $\gcd(10,7) = 1$ then $7|k\iff 7|10k$.

And $7|m \iff 7|m + 7*j$ for any $j\in \mathbb Z$.

....

Notice

$n = \sum_{i=0}^r a_i10^i$ and $m =-2a_0 +  \sum_{i=1}^r a_i10^{i-1}$.

$10m = -20a_0 +  \sum_{i=1}^r a_i10^{i}$

$10m + 21a_0 = a_0 + \sum_{i=1}^r a_i10^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^r a_i10^{i}=n$

.....

$7|m \iff 7|10m \iff 7|10m + 21a_0=n$