# is it possible to calculate mod of a very long number manually?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, big-numbers

Assuming we found a very old book with more than 1000 years old and there is an extraordinary mathematical pattern in it.
Let's say its text has 'many' clear patterns. As an example, concatenation of the number of letters of its words makes 18124 digits length number and that big number is multiple of 23. The length of the big number, 18124, is also multiple of 23. Lets say we observe many similar clear patterns and we have no doubt that there are unquestionable mathematical design patterns in the text of that book based on number 23.

The question is, a) is there any mathematical method currently to MANUALLY divide such a long number to adjust it as multiple of 23? If there is such a method, when would be the earliest approximate time to have that knowledge available in history?

b) would that be possible to make such design at that time by a community effort of many people?

If it is/was not possible, then how would you explain such observation?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "divide such a long number to adjust it as multiple of 23".

Comment: I mean the big number is designed to be multiple of 23. The author can add required words to adjust the concatenation becomes multiple of 23. Here lets say we count the number of words per sentence and concatenate per sentence. Or the concatenation of number of letters of its words makes that big number.

Comment: So you wish to know what integers $x$ can be added to a given integer $n$ to make it divisible by $23,\,$ i.e. to solve $\,x +n \equiv 0\pmod{\!23}?$  Do you know modular arithmetic / congruences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a number isn't really that big. You could do long division by hand and, even if you assume that it takes 10 seconds to extract each digit (which is likely an overestimate considering that you will gain substantial practice dividing by this specific divisor of $23$ by the time you are done), you're still only talking about 50 hours of work - not at all unreasonable and possible since antiquity. There used to be teams who did this as a [job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_(job_description)).

If you wanted to check such a large number only for divisibility by $23$, likely the easiest method would be to observe that
$$10^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}$$
meaning that to check if a number is divisible by $23$, you can just break it (going from right to left) into blocks of $22$ digits, sum up all the blocks, and see if the result is a multiple of $23$ - that'd be pretty boring as well and possibly less accessible to people from so long ago (though it's hard to say when, exactly, such a method became common knowledge - certainly by the [middle of the 17th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) at latest) - but you'd only have to do $824$ addition of numbers up to $25$ digits, followed by an easy division of a $25$ digit number by $23$. You could also easily have multiply people work at such a method - with enough help, you could surely get this done in an hour and you'd then know the remainder of your number divided by $23$. Even working alone, doing single digit additions at just one per five seconds, you're talking about less than 30 hours of work this way (and I bet if you were focussed, you could do far more than one addition per five seconds).

You would have to ask a math historian about exactly when such a method might have been available - modular arithmetic (or, perhaps more in line with how it was imagined historically: the study of linear Diophantine equations) is ***very*** old and it is easy to underestimate how clever ancient mathematicians were with algebra. It's also worth remembering how different their views were to ours: if you're talking about things more than a *thousand* years ago, you can't even take base 10 positional notation for granted so the idea to concatenate the decimal digits of something might be very unnatural to people of the age.

In the modern age, we have computers. They can do long division much faster (or use other methods). For instance, I asked Mathematica to divide a $2000$ digit number by $23$. It took 11 microseconds. Even if you don't have fast computers, long division can be implemented (essentially optimally!) by a finite state machine with $23$ states and an alphabet of the $10$ digits - so even the most rudimentary computer would have no trouble doing this division.

That said, numerology like this has a problem: there are lots of extraordinary coincidences that could occur in a set of numbers. While each one may have probabilities of only a few in a thousand, if you look hard enough and examine many possibilities, you are likely to find something interesting - but you would find the same things in random numbers.

This sort of observation is similar to what would happen if you ran a lottery among $1000$ people and then started interrogating each person about whether they had won. Most would say no, and you would not publicize this - but one would say yes and you could rightly proclaim that it was extraordinary that so-and-so won because they only had a 1/1000 chance of doing so - and even though you did not know who you would find coming into this experiment, it was certain that you would find *someone*. This is the same as if you test a set of numbers by many criteria (not to mention that there are lots of old books and lots of statistics you could associate to each one) - you do not know the result you will find, but you will probably find *something*. This doesn't make that something meaningful though.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very kind and easily followed answer. I understand your point, but lets say the probability side is out of question in my case and there is no doubt that there is a design pattern. You mentioned the knowledge of the method you described was known latest to be in 19th century. Do we have any knowledge that any people on earth  at least  before 1000 years ago knew such approach and could make a design accordingly?

Comment: @entropy You would have to ask a historian - I would hazard a guess that the method I describe or a similar one would have been accessible from a very long time ago - all you have to do is list the remainders of powers of $10$ by $23$ and see that they form a repeating pattern and you can formulate any number of methods analogous to what I describe. I think there is little doubt that this task would have been possible and it's possible that this would be the sort of idea a mathematician might think to do. They knew a lot about Diophantine equations in general (e.g. Chinese remainder theorem).

Comment: @entropy I suspect that you'd find that the potential sticking point is just about representing a number of 18124 decimal digits. It seems [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) that 1000 years ago is about when decimal notation began to be used in limited regions of the word - and of course, everything here is non-sense if we haven't got decimal notation; we can't even consider the number we are supposed to divide without it, even if we knew the theory to do so. Not to mention that they didn't exactly have endless supplies of paper either.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the last digit from $n$ to the right and multiply it by 7. Then add it to the rest of the number. If this number is a multiple of 23 then $n$ is a multiple of 23. We can rinse and repeat.

Is 18124 a multiple of 23?
It is if 1812+4*7=1840 is.
Is 1840 a multiple of 23?
It is if 184+0*7=184 is.
Is 184 a multiple of 23?
It is if 18+4*7=46 is, which clearly is.
So 18124 is a multiple of 23 by this simple algorithm.

I think this is what you are looking for?

Also let me add that it is not super hard to make a text with a multiple of 23 letters long.

Comment: Thank you but the answer seems to me it is not manually possible with big numbers.Regarding the example 18124, you performed 3 manual operations. For 18124 digits length number, this does not seem manually doable? Can you elaborate on this manual burden? Also how did you come up with 7? If the coding number was 29, what would that be or how do you determine that?

Comment: @entropy We have many prior answers on this type of divisibility test, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988853/242).