# A question on divisibility (euclid's lemma?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have come across this question, and need a bit of help understanding it.

> For integers $a$ and $b$, with $a \geq 0$ and $0 \leq b \leq 99$,  the numbers $M$ and $N$ are such that
> $$M = 100a + b$$
> $$N = a - 9b$$
> **(i)** By considering the number $M+2N$, show that $17 | M$ if and only if $17 | N$.
> **(ii)** Demonstrate step-by-step how an algorithm based on the result of part **(i)** can be used to show that $2 058 376 813 901$ is a multiple of 1 7.

For the first one, it's easy to see that $M+2N  = 102a-17b  =17(6a-b)$, though I'm not sure how to continue. I feel as if I am missing something completely.

For the second question, I was told to do as follows:
$$2 058 3768139\underline{01} \rightarrow 20583768139 - (9\times 1) = 20583768130$$
$$205837681\underline{30} \rightarrow 205837681 - (9 \times 30) = 205837411$$
$$2058374\underline{11} \rightarrow 2058374 - (9 \times 11) = 2058275 $$
$$20582\underline{75} \rightarrow 20582 - (9 \times 75) = 19907$$
$$199\underline{07} \rightarrow 199 - (9 \times 7) = 136$$
$$136 = 17 \times 8$$

However, I do not understand this solution, most likely due to the fact I lack the understanding for part **(i)**.

Comment: Special case (radix $=\color{#0a0}{100})$ of the general test in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) in the linked dupe, using $\bmod 17\!:\,\ \color{#0a0}{100\equiv -2}\Rightarrow 1/\color{#0a0}{100}\equiv 18/(\color{#0a0}{-2})\equiv \color{#c00}{-9},\,$ so $\,17\mid \color{#0a0}{100}a+b\iff 17\mid a\color{#c00}{-9}b\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track for (1). We have

$$M+2N=17(6a-b)$$

Suppose $17 \mid N$. Therefore $N=17k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitution gives us

$$M+2(17k)=17(6a-b) \implies M = 17(6a-b-2k) \implies 17 \mid M$$

Now suppose $17\mid M$. Therefore $M=17q$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitution gives us

$$17q+2N=17(6a-b) \implies 2N = 17(6a-b-q)$$

$17$ is prime, so according to [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), if $17 \mid 2N$ then at least one of $17 \mid 2$ or $17 \mid N$ is true. Since $17 \nmid 2$, we have $17 \mid N$. $\blacksquare$

For (2), we can see that

$$2058376813901=100(20583768139)+1$$

so let $M=2058376813901$. We've shown that $a$ must be $20583768139$ and $b$ must be $9(1)=9$ so we have $N=20583768139-9=20583768130$. Then you follow the solution you were provided to prove that $17 \mid N$ and use the logic from (1) and you're done.

Comment: @lulu I removed my answer for part (2) because it was mistaken. Just wanted you to know.

Comment: @lulu All fixed now.