# How to find all postive integers that are all divisible by 33 by using modular aritmetric?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How can i use modular arithmetic to find all numbers that are divisible by 33?
I have $33 = 3 \cdot 11$
Which digits sums are positive integers in base 10.

Can i use the euclidean algorithm to find all the postive integers that are divisible by 33 and then back-track with the extended euclidean algorithm to find all x or y but i'dont know which numbers i have to use in the Euclidean algorithm.

And $gcd(3,11) = 1$

Are i on the right trail to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand.  They all look like $33 \cdot k$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: You are looking for the [divisibility rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for $3$ and $11$

Comment: @Randall my answer below provides a more interesting method than "they all look like $33k$ for some integer $k$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Euclidean algorithm, which involves a lot of divisions, then you may as well just divide *once* by $33$ and look at the remainder: $33 \mid n$ if and only if the remainder when $n$ is divided by $33$ is $0$. That is not very interesting mathematically and I suspect it is not what you're looking for as a method.

Here is a much more interesting method to test if a positive integer $n$ is divisible by $33$.
Write $n = 10n' + a$, so $a$ is the units digit of $n$. Then $n$ is divisible by $33$ *if and only if* $n' + 10a$ is divisible by $33$, and since $n' + 10a$ is typically smaller than $n$ we get a recursive procedure that will bring us down to a small number that we can directly check for divisibility by $33$.

**Example**. Let $n = 24354$. Then $n' = 2435 + 10\cdot 4 = 2475$. We continue this process:
$$
24354 \leadsto 2475 \leadsto 247 + 10\cdot 5 = 297 \leadsto 29 + 10\cdot 7 = 99,
$$
and $99$ is divisible by $33$, so the original number is divisible by $33$.  In fact, $24354 = 33 \cdot 738$.

**Example**. Let $n = 5823$.  Then we look at
$$
5823 \leadsto 582 + 30 = 612 \leadsto 61 + 20 = 81 \leadsto 8+10=18,
$$
and $18$ is not divisible by $33$, so the original number $5823$ is not divisible by $33$.

This method does not appear to involve modular arithmetic, but it does behind the scenes: $33 \mid n$ if and only if $33 \mid (n'+ 10a)$ because $10^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 33$:
$$
n \equiv 0 \bmod 33 \Longleftrightarrow 
10n' + a \equiv 0 \bmod 33 \Longleftrightarrow 
n' + 10a \equiv 0 \bmod 33,  
$$
where we multiplied through by $10$ (an invertible number modulo $33$) in the last equivalence.

This method is a special case of what I call a "universal divisibility test" for divisibility by numbers $m$ that are relatively prime to $10$. It is based on using the inverse of $10 \bmod m$, and when $m = 33$ the number $10$ happens to be its own inverse mod $33$. For more information and examples of this approach, which is based on modular arithmetic for its justification but does not involve modular arithmetic when carrying out the method, look [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/universaldivtest.pdf).

Comment: Of course this and variants has been proved here many times in the past, e.g. it is the [special case of $\,t=3\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) of $10t+3\mid 10b+a \iff 10t+3\mid b+(1+3t)a,\,$ which is a special case of a more general divisibility test proved there. Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).