# Divisibility Rules

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

In mathematics different integer also that mean different rule to for divisibility of integer, But this is not flexible way to learn divisibility of Integer then Is there another way, maybe some kind of formula to learn it? And also if there is, please provide the source, I would really appreciate it

Comment: The common divsibility tests are special cases of a general test, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) in the linked dupe. Please search for answers before posting questions.

Comment: There are unfortunately only easy rules for quite a small amount of numbers.

Comment: @Peter There are easy rules for *every* integer, e.g. see the Theorem at the end [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2989299/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque Seems that we disagree what "easy" is.

Comment: @Peter What is not "easy" about tests like the following proved there?
$$\begin{align} 19\mid 10b+a\iff 19\mid b+2a\\ 
29\mid 10b+a\iff 29\mid b+3a\\ 
39\mid 10b+a\iff 39\mid b+4a \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$